# Creating a Remote in Xcode, Keep getting Unknown error occured

Tags: xcode, git, github

I have added my Github account into my Xcode project and did all the things with the Token, but when I try to create a Remote in my project it just tells me "Unknown Error Occured". I've looked on the forums and all the issues were from half a decade ago with what I'm assuming to be redundant solutions since they have not worked for me. [this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nph1k.png)

Tried no capitalization in the remote name, no change. Tried a new token, no change. Reconnected my account, no change. Cleaned the project, no change. restarted Xcode, no change.

Comment: Don't try to do anything with Git in Xcode. It just gets in your way, and no one can help if there's a problem. Learn to use Git at the command line, and be productive and happy.

Comment: I have started getting the same error and trying to work out what is causing it.